# In Dynamic-Data how do I get the results count of a DynamicFilter?

Tags: dynamic-data, asp.net-dynamic-data

I have a Dynamic-Data application with a List.aspx main page listing data which can be filtered by country. The country table is used as a DynamicFilter as it is a foreignkey to the main table.

When I choose a state the DynamicFilter_FilterChanged method fires and it filters the main table properly but I'm trying to figure out how I can get the total number of rows that the filtering has produced.

I've looked at previous posts here with no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can count when the Gridview on the list.aspx page is selected

```
protected void GridDataSource_Selected(object sender, LinqDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.TotalRowCount > 0)
    {
        lblCount.Text = e.TotalRowCount.ToString() + ((e.TotalRowCount == 1) ? " item found." : " items found.");
    }
}
```

Comment: When does this method fire?  I added this code and when I click the Country drop-down list and select a country the GridView gets filtered properly but this method never fires.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't included.  This fires on the OnSelected Event on the LinqDataSource (or whatever data source) that populates the Gridview.

Comment: I guess the Gridview datasource is not being selected because this method "GridDataSource_Selected" is not being fired?

Comment: Do you have OnSelected="GridDataSource_Selected" in your LinqDataSource tage?